# How to scheduling System Image Backup in Windows 8.1 on network location

Tags: windows, backup, nas

I trying to setup System Image backup to be mad every week.
I found really
[good tutorial how to do that.](https://www.winhelp.us/system-image-backup-in-windows-8-1.html)

But im stuck in the part where i have to add arguments for powershell.exe. Tutorial explaining how to make backup on connected storage but i want to make backup to NAS via local network. So how do i need to modify this line:

```
wbAdmin start backup -backupTarget:E: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet
```

To specify user / password and how should i add path where i want backup to be stored.

Btw. i want to store it at:

```
\\QNAP-STORAGE\home\RecoveryPoints\SystemImage
```

Comment: Anyone ? Im sure someone have to know the answer :)